# When using bind(), arguments are passed by reference even if ref() adaptor is not used

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace placeholders;

void f(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}

void g(int& a, int& b)
{
    a *= 2;
    b *= 3;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    int b = 200;
    auto greversed = bind(g,_2,_1);
    greversed(b,a);
    f(a,b);
    greversed(ref(b),ref(a));
    f(a,b);
}
```

Based on my reading of "The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition" (Stroustrup) p. 968 I would expect that during the first call to greversed(b,a) that a copy of a and b would be passed by reference to g() and that only the second call would actually pass a and b to g() by reference.

The example code given on p. 968:

```
void incr(int& i)
{
    ++i;
}

void user()
{
    int i =1;
    incr(i);                     // i becomes 2
    auto inc = bind(incr,_1);
    inc(i);                     // i stays 2; inc(i) incremented a local copy of i
}
```

Running this code, i is incremented twice, despite what the comments say.

For my program, my expected output would be:

```
100 200
200 600
```

However, when I compile this code under Ubuntu using "g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp" I get the following output:

```
200 600
400 1800
```

It appears a and b are passed by reference no matter if the ref() adaptor are used or not.

Comment: Why would you expect a copy of a and b? The function returned by bind is just asking for two references

Comment: [Interestingly...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dd29440a20d139d)

Comment: @chris that surprised me

Comment: I've edited the original question and added the sample code from the Stroustrup book.  Maybe just a mistake on the author's part?  As pointed out in the accepted answer, the ref() adaptor is not required for placeholder arguments.

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug in the book, and doesn't seem to be listed in the [errata](http://stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html) either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Introduction

`std::placeholders::_*` works by *perfectly-forwarding* the types which later takes their place.

This mean that since you are passing *a* and *b* (which are *lvalues*) to *greversed* these *lvalues* will be *forwarded* to `g`, exactly like they are.

This behavior is explained in section `[func.bind.bind]p10` of the Standard ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), but a more easy to understand explanation can be found here:

- [**cppreference.com** - **`std::bind`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

---

#### Source of confusion

I haven't read the book you are referring to, but your confusion probably lies in the fact that `std::bind` will not bind a reference to the passed in argument when you use a *non-placeholder*, instead it will **copy** the argument.

This below example hopefully aids in understanding the difference between using a *std::placeholder*, and passing in a value to be bound.

```
int main () {
  auto f = [](int& r1, int& r2) {
    r1 *= 2;
    r2 *= 2;
  };

  int  a = 1;
  int  b = 2;

  auto x = std::bind (f, a, std::placeholders::_1); // a copy of `a` will be stored
                                                    // inside `x`

  x (b);  // pass the copy of `a`, and perfectly-forward `b`, to `f`
              
  std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
}
```

```
a: 1
b: 4
```